# action cable reconnect fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using ActionCable for a multi tenancy application.
I authenticate my connection via:

```
identified_by :current_user

def connect
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
  logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', "User #{current_user.id}"
end

protected

def find_verified_user
  # pry.binding
  if current_user = User.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
    current_user
  else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
  end
end
```

which on first request connects fine:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-04 17:57:41 +0000
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-04 17:57:41 +0000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "kanyi"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] [User 1] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vYmx1ZW9yaWdpbnMvVXNlci8x)
[ActionCable] [User 1]   Chatroom Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms"
[ActionCable] [User 1] ChatroomsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:58:03 +0000
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:58:03 +0000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

but on the second attempt, action cable rejects the connection;

```
User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:58:03 +0000
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-01-04 17:58:03 +0000
```

What is causing the second request from failing?

Comment: From the logs, it looks like the second request does not have the subdomain set as "kanyi".

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1: HTTP upgrade request for actionable:**

The resolution that needs a NGINX configuration changes to accept this action cable request.

```
location / {
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Add the above lines to your location block in the nginx site configuration, then restart nginx. This problem should be resolve.

link: [resource](https://www.xploralab.com/2019/01/24/actioncable-failed-to-upgrade-to-websocket-in-production/)

**Problem 2: unauthorized connection attempt**

I am coming back to your next problem which is "An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected"

this problem reside on your **'connection.rb'** file. you need to check how you are authorising a user to use action cable. check your function **"find_verified_user"** in ***'connection.rb'***.

specifically this line `"User.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)"` is not working.

hope it helps,

Thanks